# SQL: How to get the sum of all strings in rows of sentences of a column

Tags: sql

```
|                        random_column                         |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| The magnetic quality of a sample of iron depends on the purity|
| A sample is taken from each bale separately.                  |
| I love Switzerland                                            |
| Be sure to sample the chocolate-walnut torte                  |
| Mary had a little lamb                                        |
| This is a very cool table                                     |
```

Is there an sql query that is able to split all the sentences into strings, tally them and return the top 3 most frequent strings?

eg:-

```
|   string   | sum |
|-------------|-----|
|    cool     |  5  |
|    love     |  3  |
|    lamb     |  2  |
```

Comment: PostgreSQL has full text search capabilities. MySQL does not have any out of the box, but maybe there's some kind of plugin out there...

Comment: @Pavitran . . . There is not a simple mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can parse the words with something like this:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n
     ) n join
     t
     on col like concat(repeat('% ', n.n - 1), '%');
```

Note that this version only gets the first three words.  You need to expand `n` for the maximum number of words in the column.

Then you can aggregate as:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(t.col, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word,
       count(*)
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n
     ) n join
     t
     on col like concat(repeat('% ', n.n - 1), '%')
group by word
```